# How to trigger checkboxes with XFDF

Tags: pdf, xfdf

Here is what I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields>
<field name="text1">
<value>First Last</value>
<field name="checkbox1">
<value>yes</value>
</field>
<field name="checkbox2">
<value></value>
</field>
<ids original="xxxxx" modified="1331062234" />
<f href="http://example.com/test.pdf" />
</xfdf>
```

The text value gets entered in the PDF, but I can't figure out how to get the checkboxes to recognize that they are checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="yes" />
```

The xfdf value entry needs to match the checkbox value:

```
<field name="checkbox_name">
   <value>yes</value>
</field>
```

Comment: How do you know what the value of the checkbox is?